# What is the difference between loading my index html file vs. using http-server?

Tags: google-chrome, npm, development-environment, httpserver, web-development-server

I learning to code and have played around with npm, webpack, and http-server. I usually use http-server and then open up local host to see the changes that I've made through React that ends up on index.html. But I notice that this works too if I just open the index.html file in Chrome or another browser. What's the point of opening http-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some cases require a server, like ajax. Many things don't require a server, but after a while developers just get used to having a local server around.

Comment: why ajax require a server?

Comment: I'm guessing that for Javascript to load a local file it would be a security risk. Anyways, there's a difference between what comes back from a server and loading a local file. The server sends back response headers.